# Is is possible to deactivate outlining in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I do not like outlining in SSMS. Is it possible to turn it off by default in the options for every new query?

I check already the options but did not find any.

Comment: For new features, suggest on [SQL Server feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

open tools > options and search for intellisense, then uncheck "Outline statements"

Comment: It's under **Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>Transact-SQL=>IntelliSense**

Comment: More specifically:
1. Select **Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>Transact-SQL=>IntelliSense**, then deselect **Outline statements**.
2. However, in some cases, for reasons that aren’t clear, you may also have to open a query in the editor and then select **Edit=>Outlining=>Stop Outlining**.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for doesn't exist but you can achieve this using the menu option in the Query Editor.

Open your query and then go to Edit > Outlining > Toggle All Outlining  : this will expand/collapse all the nodes in your query.

Comment: But I need to do it in every query session again

Comment: Make a keyboard shortcut in Options->Environment->Keyboard and find Edit.ToggleAllOutlining